# Oracle DB on Amazon's EC2 + EBS

Tags: oracle, amazon-ec2, database-administration, amazon-ebs

I just installed Oracle on my Amazon's Virtual EC2 Linux (Ubuntu) Server. Because i'm not really familiar with Oracle Database Administration I'm wondering what files and how i need to move to ESB so when i shut down or terminate my instance the data won't be lost.

I have found [THIS](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/RenamingOrMovingOracleFiles.php) tutorial, but i'm not sure if this is what i need.

Comment: Seems like a slightly better fit for ServerFault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Backup your database
2. Follow these instructions:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/paa/obe-dbf/html/Move_DF.htm
http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/Database_Administration/DBA_35.shtml

Answer (score 2):

You might want to start with one of the Oracle AMIs for simplicity.  You can find them here:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/cloud/index.html

and an overview of Oracle on EC2 is here:

http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/featured-partners/oracle/

Watch the demo video there.  As you follow along, make sure you've pre-mounted your EBS on the node.  When the video gets to the part where you specify the data locations, use your EBS mount point.